# Number of Subarray whose sum greater than given value

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Given an array of *N* integers (positive and negative), find the number of **contiguous** sub array whose sum is greater or equal to *K (also, positive or negative)*

I have managed to work out a naive O(N<sup>2</sup>) solution, is it possible to get better?

Comment: What's the star for?

Comment: Do the subarrays have to be contiguous?

Comment: @jasonN oops . typo. will fix that

Comment: @Imran yes. will add that to the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do it in `O(n log n)` time.

1. Let's take a look at prefix sums. A sum of a `(L, R]` subarray is `prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L]`.
2. It means that we can count the number of such `L` and `R` that `L < R` and `prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L] >= K`, which means `prefixSum[L] <= prefixSum[R] - K`.
3. Let's iterate over the array of prefix sums from left to right and maintain a data structure that can do the following operations efficiently :

   - Add a new element.
   - Find the number of elements less than or equal to a given number.

   We can use a balanced binary search tree for this purpose.

Here is a pseudo-code of this solution:

```
tree = an empty search tree
result = 0
// This sum corresponds to an empty prefix.
prefixSum = 0
tree.add(prefixSum) 
// Iterate over the input array from left to right.
for elem <- array:
    prefixSum += elem
    // Add the number of subarrays that have this element as the last one
    // and their sum is not less than K.
    result += tree.getNumberOfLessOrEqual(prefixSum - K) 
    // Add the current prefix sum the tree.
    tree.add(prefixSum)
print result
```

The time complexity is `O(n log n)` because there are `O(n)` add and count number of elements operations, and each of them can be done in `O(log n)`.

Comment: This is an amazing soln. If somebody has a Python implementation of this lying around, do share

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution, which uses Divide and Conquer method. Time complexity is `O(n lg n)`.

The first two steps are just like above post:

1. Create prefix sums, let's call them `prefixSum[]`.
2. It means that we have to count the number of such `L` and `R` that `L < R` and `prefixSum[R] - prefixSum[L] >= K`.
3. Now, let's make another array, let's call it `arr[]`, where `arr[i] = prefixSum[N - 1 - i]` for `i` from `0` to `N - 1`. This means that we are creating a reversed `prefixSum[]` array.

Now we have to count the number of such `i` and `j` that `i < j` and `arr[i] - arr[j] >= K`. To do this, we'll use Merge Sort (which uses D & C method):

Suppose that we have:

```
MergeSort(arr, left, right):
    mid = (left + right) / 2
    MergeSort(arr, left, mid)
    MergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right)
    Merge(arr, left, mid, right)
```

In `Merge` function, we have to add this:

```
i = left - mid       # Index for the left array
j = mid + 1 - right  # Index for the right array

if (arr[i] >= arr[j]):
    if (arr[i] >= arr[j] + K):
        count += (mid - i + 1)
        # Because arr[] from i to mid are all
        # greater or equal to arr[i] so if arr[i] >= arr[j] + K
        # then arr[] from i to mid are all >= arr[j] + K.
else:
    if (arr[i] >= arr[j] + K): # K can be negative.
        count += mid - i + 1;
```

The idea is the same to count Inversion in an array
https://www.cdn.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/