# O(n) solution to counting sub-arrays with sum constraints

Tags: algorithm, subset, complexity-theory, subset-sum

I'm trying to improve my intuition around the following two sub-array problems.

**Problem one**

```
Return the length of the shortest, non-empty, contiguous sub-array of A with sum at least 
K. If there is no non-empty sub-array with sum at least K, return -1
```

I've come across an `O(N)` [solution](https://leetcode.com/articles/shortest-subarray-with-sum-atleast-k/) online.

```
public int shortestSubarray(int[] A, int K) {
    int N = A.length;
    long[] P = new long[N+1];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        P[i+1] = P[i] + (long) A[i];

    // Want smallest y-x with P[y] - P[x] >= K
    int ans = N+1; // N+1 is impossible
    Deque<Integer> monoq = new LinkedList(); //opt(y) candidates, as indices of P

    for (int y = 0; y < P.length; ++y) {
        // Want opt(y) = largest x with P[x] <= P[y] - K;
        while (!monoq.isEmpty() && P[y] <= P[monoq.getLast()])
            monoq.removeLast();
        while (!monoq.isEmpty() && P[y] >= P[monoq.getFirst()] + K)
            ans = Math.min(ans, y - monoq.removeFirst());

        monoq.addLast(y);
    }

    return ans < N+1 ? ans : -1;
}
```

It seems to be maintaining a sliding window with a deque. It looks like a variant of Kadane's algorithm.

**Problem two**

```
Given an array of N integers (positive and negative), find the number of 
contiguous sub array whose sum is greater or equal to K (also, positive or 
negative)"
```

The best solution I've seen to this problem is `O(nlogn)` as described in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28272579/3952442).

```
tree = an empty search tree
result = 0
// This sum corresponds to an empty prefix.
prefixSum = 0
tree.add(prefixSum) 
// Iterate over the input array from left to right.
for elem <- array:
    prefixSum += elem
    // Add the number of subarrays that have this element as the last one
    // and their sum is not less than K.
    result += tree.getNumberOfLessOrEqual(prefixSum - K) 
    // Add the current prefix sum the tree.
    tree.add(prefixSum)
print result
```

**My questions**

1. Is my intuition that algorithm one is a variant of Kandane's algorithm correct?
2. If so, is there a variant of this algorithm (or another `O(n)` solution) that can be used to solve problem two?
3. Why can problem two only be solved in `O(nlogn)` time when they look so similar?